# C# Remove object from list stored in an ASP session

Tags: linq, session, listbox

I am making a small eBook Store as a project. I am storing the cart in the ASP session as a list of objects. Now, in the checkout page, I am showing that list of objects in a list box and allowing the user to delete an item if needed. This is my code

`protected void btnCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Title> cartItems = (List<Title>)Session["eStoreCart"];
        int itemToRemove = Int32.Parse(lbCartItems.SelectedItem.Value);
        Title ttl = ebs.Titles.SingleOrDefault(t => t.TitleId == itemToRemove);
        cartItems.Remove(ttl);
        Session["eStoreCart"] = cartItems;
        FillListBox();
    }`
Apparently, the number of items in `cartItems` are same before and after the Remove() method is called. Where am I going wrong?
A similar method was used in Add to Card with `cartItems.Add(ttl)`, which is working flawlessly.

Comment: On the surface it looks like this should work.  Examine `Session["eStoreCart"]` in a debugger after re-assigning.

Comment: While debugging, I was looking at the count of `cartItems`. That seems to remain the same even after the Remove. Therefore, the Session remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
  Title ttl = ebs.Titles.SingleOrDefault(t => t.TitleId == itemToRemove);
```

Try

```
 Title ttl = cartItems.SingleOrDefault(t => t.TitleId == itemToRemove);
```

i.e. instead of searching for the Title in 'ebs' (not sure what it contains, as not clear in OP code), search for items in Session Object directly and then remove it.

Comment: `ebs` is the database. I made a Design First database in Entity framework and generated it in SQL server.

Comment: ok, but after making code changes as mentioned above, is it working ? Also, are your Db Entities (Title class generated by EF) different then the (Title) class used in web page.

Answer (score 0):

The `.Remove()` method [is going to check for equality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx) when trying to remove the item.  Does `Title` [implement `IEquatable<Title>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)?  If not then the check for equality is going to be default, which for objects is reference equality.  And it's unlikely that reference equality is being satisfied here.

Implementing `IEquatable<Title>` is probably the ideal approach here.  Just add that interface to the `Title` implementation and implement its one method:

```
public bool Equals(Title other) 
{
    if (other == null) 
        return false;

    if (this.SomeValue == other.SomeValue)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

This would put the equality logic on the model where it belongs.  Failing that, your code would have to be more procedural in checking for equality.  That is, you'd first have to find the element in `cartItems` that you're looking for and then remove *that* object, rather than trying to remove an object which itself exists in `ebs.Titles`.  Something like:

```
cartItems.Remove(cartItems.Single(c => c.SomeValue == ttl.SomeValue));
```

That way the code is referencing the same in-memory object, not just an object that intuitively represents the same thing.

Comment: I am trying to remove the object from the list stored in the session. If I remove it from `cartItems`, the session, which populates the listbox, does not get updated.

Comment: @RanganDas: That's the point, are you *actually* removing the element from `cartItems`?  If the session isn't being updated, then presumably the item itself isn't being removed.  You never check if the item *exists* in `cartItems` before or after trying to remove it.  So if it's not there, there's nothing to remove.  And whether or not the item *exists* in the list depends on how the system compares for equality.

Comment: Thank you so much on providing the insight on the equality checking mechanism. I used this code and it works.

`List<Title> cartItems = (List<Title>)Session["eStoreCart"];
        int itemToRemove = Int32.Parse(lbCartItems.SelectedItem.Value);
        Title ttl = cartItems.SingleOrDefault(c => c.TitleId == itemToRemove);
        cartItems.Remove(ttl);
        Session["eStoreCart"] = cartItems;
        FillListBox();
`